# Is it possible to comment out multiple paragraphs in preamble?

Tags: comments, preamble

I wonder if there is a way to comment out many paragraphs in preamble. I learned that in the document one can utilize the Comment package. I would like to do the same within the preamble.

Comment: Using the `comment` environment (from [`comment`](//ctan.org/pkg/comment)) works in the document as well as the preamble. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Werner, Hi, Thanks. I tried that yes, with the package put before and after the \begin{comment} \end{comment}

Comment: [This code](https://pastebin.com/raw/ptAMt9uA) compiles without problem. You can even define the `comment` environment using [`environ`](//ctan.org/pkg/environ) (like `\usepackage{environ} \NewEnviron{comment}{}`). If this doesn't work for you, please post some code that replicates your problematic behaviour.

Comment: I am not sure what you really need, but does enclosing your paragraphs with ‘\iffalse’ and ‘\fi’ do the job?

Comment: As an alternative, in most editors, you can select the paragraphs and comment them. Even quicker with regular expressions: 33,124s/^/% in vim would comment out lines 33 to 124.